# Php Yii : to have custom client validation

Tags: php, validation, yii

I am making a progressive stage registration form.
I am storing the **$POST['']['']** value in **Yii::app()->session['']**
And inserting into Database after the last step.

Now i figured that i need to use **scenarios** for each of my registration page.

***Question :***
How do i validate each registration page without the values being stored
by **$model->save()** ?

***What I have done :***

**Controller.php**

```
public actionCreate($id){
       $model=new Admission;
       if($id==0){
            $model->setscenario('student');  
            Yii::app()->session['percent'] = 0;
            if(isset($_POST['Admission']))
            {
                Yii::app()->session['admissionStudent'] = $_POST['Admission'];          

                if($model->validate('student')){
                    Yii::app()->session['percent'] = 25;
                    $this->redirect(array('create','id'=>$id+1));                               
                }
                else{
                        var_dump($model->getErrors());
                }
            }
        }
}
```

**Create_Form.php**

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('bootstrap.widgets.TbActiveForm',array(
            'id'=>'admission-form',
            //'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
            //'htmlOptions' => array('enctype'=>'multipart/form-data'),
)); ?>

 <?php echo $form->textFieldRow($model,'Name',array('class'=>'span4')); ?>  

 /* And other Fields */

<?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array(
    'buttonType'=>'submit',
    'type'=>'primary',
    'label'=>$model->isNewRecord ? 'Next' : 'Save & Proceed',
)); ?>
```

**Model.php**

```
public function rules()
    {
        return array(
    array('Name,dob,SchoolLastAttended,
     StandardLastStudied,QualifiedForPromotion,age,sex,medium',   
    'required','on'=>'student'),
   }
```

***Errors***

It shows every field is blank and Returns Validation Error

var_dump

```
array(8) { ["Name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(41) "Name of the Pupil 
cannot be blank." } ["dob"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(37) "Date of 
Birth cannot be blank." } ["SchoolLastAttended"]=> array(1) { [0]=> 
string(71) "Name of the School last attended Primary/Middle cannot be 
blank." } ["StandardLastStudied"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(45) 
"Standard Last Studied cannot be blank." } ["QualifiedForPromotion"]=> 
array(1) { [0]=> string(70) "Whether qualified for promotion to 
Standard VI cannot be  blank." } ["age"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(27)
 "Age cannot be blank." } ["sex"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(27) "Sex
 cannot be blank." } ["medium"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(30) "Medium
 cannot be blank." } }
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my answer, I feel so stupid. Just in case anyone faces a similar kind of problem.

Add

```
$model->attributes = $_POST['Admission'];
```

to the **Controller** action:

```
public actionCreate($id){
   $model=new Admission;
    if($id==0){
        $model->setScenario('student');  
        Yii::app()->session['percent'] = 0;
        if(isset($_POST['Admission']))
        {
            $model->attributes = $_POST['Admission'];
            if($model->validate('student')){
                Yii::app()->session['admissionStudent'] = $_POST['Admission'];          
                Yii::app()->session['percent'] = 25;
                $this->redirect(array('create','id'=>$id+1));
            }
        }
    }
}
```